# Import code works when typed into Shell. but not when running py.script?

Tags: python

I'm having some problem understanding this.

The imported code works successfully when I run the command directly in shell, but it fails when I run the identical code in a .py file

[image]
I tried downgrading to 3.5 after getting the same error in 3.7

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code.

Comment: You're using the name of the library as the script name. This overrides the library module. Change the file name to something else and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've called your local script "goodreads", so Python tries to import that rather than the library. Name your script something else.